# Characterizing functors $\mathscr A\times\mathscr B\to\mathscr C$

Tags: category-theory, functors

I'm working on Exercise 1.2.25 from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf.

Parts (a) and (b) are straightforward as far as I understand, but I'm not sure how to do (c). I can define the functor $F$ on objects in at least two ways: $F((A,B))=F^A(B)$ or $F((A,B))=F_B(A)$. According to (b), these two agree, so we can choose either definition. But I don't know how to define $F$ on morphisms and how to use the second condition in (b). Further, jumping to the question of uniqueness, is there a standard technique to prove it?

Comment: (b) gives the equality of two compositions of morphisms. Use their common value as the definition of $F(f,g)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see; so the first condition in (b) is needed to prove $F(1)=1$ and the second condition is needed to prove $F(fg)=F(f)F(g)$. But how would one prove uniqueness?

Comment: You should endeavor to make your questions reasonably self-contained. If the link broke or the document changed, this question would become meaningless. Even with a working link, it is tedious to dig through a large document just to see what you're talking about. It should be possible to know what the question is without referring to the document. This includes definitions of notation or less common concepts. If you want, you could also provide a sentence or two describing what has been introduced so that you don't get answers using concepts that haven't yet been introduced.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132359/show-that-a-functor-with-a-domain-a-%c3%97-b-can-be-regarded-as-a-pair-of-families-of